# Which X works if I use class name 'X' which is same as type parameter placeholder 'X' used in generic method?

Tags: java, generics

I found it in the SCJP guide book. The code looks like this.

```
class X {
    public <X> X(X x) { } 
}
```

The book said it's valid.

> If you REALLY want to get ridiculous (or fired), you can declare a
>   class with a name that is the same as the type parameter placeholder.

Will 'X' in method parameter act differently for what it's given? 
For example;

`new X(xObj)` => Class kind of X works.

`new X(dog)` => Type parameter kind of X works.

I'm currently not available to test run the code. So can somebody please enlighten me. Thanks.

Comment: Looks valid to me: https://ideone.com/5peqBf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor type-parameter *hides* the type `X`, which the class defines.

If you do:

```
X something = new X("hello");
```

then the type-parameter `X` will be replaced by `String`.

Furthermore, suppose you define a `List<X>` within the constructor's body and add the provided argument to the list:

```
List<X> list = new ArrayList<X>();
list.add(x);
```

Having `new X("hello")` will make the `List` to be parameterized by `String` (but not by the type `X` the the `class X` defines) and will contain the provided `"hello"` literal.

To summarize, you must follow some basic naming conventions and avoid creating such classes with such type-parameters, because this is completely against any code clean principles. Even though the code compiles, it's difficult to be read. Remember that programming is not only about *talking* to the computer, but it's about *talking* (via your code) to the people will maintain your code in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Within the argument list it is the generic argument. Looks like within the class whenever you refer to X - that always refer to `class X` - I couldn't find a way to make it refer to the generic argument.

A small sample:

```
package snippet;

public class X {
    private Object x;

    public <X> X(X x) {
        this.x =  x;
        X y ;
        y = x ;
        System.out.println(y.getClass());
    }

    @Override public String toString() {
        return x.getClass().getName();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        X x = new X(10);
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

It prints

```
class java.lang.Integer
java.lang.Integer
```

Answer (score 0):

When writing this code in eclipse, a hint shows and say "The type parameter X is hiding the type X" so I assume X (the class) is not available in this scope and all references to X will be linked to the type parameter X.